# Monospace tabular numbers in Android TextViews

Tags: android, fonts, textview, monospace

I have a custom font which has variable-width numeric glyphs by default, and I would like to use the font's monospace tabular numbers feature in an Android `TextView` so that numbers align vertically.

That is, change something like this:

[image]

to something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To select a font's tabular number feature, use `TextView`'s [`fontFeatureSettings`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFontFeatureSettings(java.lang.String)) with [`tnum`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts/#tabular-nums):

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:fontFeatureSettings="tnum"
    android:text="1111.11\n2222.22"
    />
```

Requires API level 21.

Comment: (Self-documenting something I learned today with no existing SO posts found.)

Comment: Or you can set it programmatically on the textview 
setFontFeatureSettings()

Comment: Thanks for sharing that @laalto. Here is how to do it using Jetpack Compose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68995057/2521749