# Monospace numbers in the Jetpack Compose Text component

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I'm using a custom font within my Jetpack Compose app and would like to monospace the numbers within a specific Text component.

With standard Android TextView, this can be done using the `fontFeatureSetting="tnum"` attribute (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41143337/2521749).

How can you do this with Jetpack Compose?

[image: Countdown clock]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`buildAnnotatedString` is needed to customize different parts of a string.

If you need to apply some text style to the whole `Text`, you can use `style` argument.

```
Text(
    text = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%02d:%02d", mins, secs),
    style = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(fontFeatureSettings = "tnum"),
)
```

I'm using `LocalTextStyle.current` here, which is the default style for `Text`, but you can replace it with the one you need, like one of your theme typography: `MaterialTheme.typography.h4`

Comment: Yep, this is better. Thanks Phillip!

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using an annotated string and [SpanStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/SpanStyle).

```
    Text(
        text = buildAnnotatedString {
            withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontFeatureSettings = "tnum")) {
                append(String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%02d:%02d", mins, secs))
            }
        }
    )
```

By default, numbers are displayed using the `propotional-nums` setting which allows the number to take only as much space as it needs. `tabular-num` or
[tnum](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts/#ref-for-valdef-font-variant-numeric-tabular-nums) forces all numbers to take up the same amount of space for the given font size. This allow you to render numbers in a monospaced-like format which is useful for views that update the numbers or for a table-like view that displays numbers.

The result is a view that will take up the same amount of space no matter the number displayed in it:

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Too bad it didn't work for hexadecimal numbers as well.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
val fontFamily = FontFamily(Typeface(android.graphics.Typeface.MONOSPACE))
buildAnnotatedString.addStyle(SpanStyle(fontFamily = fontFamily), start, end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val textStyle = TextStyle(
    fontSize = textWithoutScale(size = 26f),
    color = gray900,
    fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
    letterSpacing = 7.sp,
    fontFamily = FontFamily(Typeface.MONOSPACE) //Here's the magic!
)
```